# modified list input when character value has embedded blanks

Tags: input, sas

I am preparing SAS BASE test. In the test book chapter 17 Reading Free-format Data, there is an example about how to read character values with embedded blanks and nonstandard value, such as numbers with comma. I tested it and its result is not what the book described.

```
data cityrank;
infile datalines;
input rank city & $12. pop86: comma.;
datalines;
1 NEW YORK 7,262,700
2 LOS ANGELES 3,259,340
3 CHICAGO 3,009,530
4 HOUSTON 1,728,910
5 PHILADELPHIA 1,642,900
6 DETROIT 1,086,220
7 DAN DIEGO 1,015,190
8 DALLAS 1,003,520
9 SAN ANTONIA 914,350
;
```

what I got is like below, data set has 4 obs.

```
rank city          pop86
1    NEW YORK 7,2  2
3    CHICAGO 3,00  4
5    PHILADELPHIA  6
7    DAN DIEGO 1,  8
```

Am I wrong somewhere typing the program? I have checked again and again that I copy it correctly.

How to modify this program?

Thank you!

Comment: I thought at least Philadelphia can get correct Pop86 value, but still not. don't understand why for this city. others because character length is 12. very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing from the typos that you didn't copy-paste this, but you typed it in instead.

As such, you (or the book writers) made another typo: there are *two* spaces after the city names, not one (or at least, should be).  That's what the `&` does: it says "wait for two consecutive delimiters" (allowing a single delimiter to be ignored, so `New York` is read into one variable instead of split).

So this would be correct:

```
data cityrank;
infile datalines;
input rank city & $12. pop86: comma.;
datalines;
1 NEW YORK  7,262,700
2 LOS ANGELES  3,259,340
3 CHICAGO  3,009,530
4 HOUSTON  1,728,910
5 PHILADELPHIA  1,642,900
6 DETROIT  1,086,220
7 SAN DIEGO  1,015,190
8 DALLAS  1,003,520
9 SAN ANTONIO  914,350
;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe! You right and book does say that so, two or more consecutive delimiters. Now it works as the book describes.

Comment: But I am still wondering in the real world, what if a raw data in my first post exists. what should we do to read the records correctly? Thank you!

Comment: In the real world, you wouldn't have a good solution without quite a lot of work, because there's no obvious way to tell the read-in that "NEW YORK" is one field.  You'd have to perform some preprocessing, likely, that would identify that a naive read-in would put "YORK" in a numeric field, and then quote the field ("NEW YORK" would then, if you use the DSD option, be read in as one field).  But in real world scenarios that's often very messy.

Comment: Agree, because I did several tests, like change the "blank" delimiter to be comma, put " " marks for numbers, add DSD, use informat statement before input...all doesn't work. So the best and easy way is just add one more blank before the numbers. :) Thank you so much for your time and answers!